# How to serve and browse static folder with html files without using layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I'm building a website based on a bought theme.  I want to serve the theme folder so my customer can have a look at the unmodified version of theme and choose components.

With express, i can do this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/theme', express.static('my_theme', {'icons': true}));
```

I didn't find how to do this with total.js.

Comment: Hi you can place the folder in public directory `./public/theme` or alernatively create a mapping using `F.map();` see docs for more https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~Framework~framework.map

Comment: How could I not figure it out !  Tank you, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Put theme folder inside public/ folder works but, bought theme are usually shipped with a documentation folder and more so it could be useful to browse them.
total.js provide a module to browse folder : [directorylisting](https://github.com/totaljs/modules/tree/master/Miscellaneous/directorylisting). It work well with public folder but take a note it doesn't with F.map() who provide a way to map a folder.